# What does "coarse" mean in the context of probability bounds and Markov's inequality?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, quantum-information

In John Watrous's *The Theory of Quantum Information* the author introduces Markov's inequality as follows:

> The first theorem to be stated in this subsection is Markov’s inequality, which provides a **sometimes coarse** upper bound on the probability that a nonnegative random variable exceeds a given threshold value.

Also, in this section the author clarifies that

> the theorem statements that follow should be understood to apply to random variables distributed with respect to Borel probability measures.

The inequality itself as stated as follows:

> **Theorem 1.13** (Markov’s inequality) Let X be a random variable taking nonnegative real values, and let ε > 0 be a positive real number. It holds that
>
> $${\text{Pr}(X\geq\epsilon) \leq \frac{E(X)}{\epsilon}}.$$

Where previously the following notational convention was established:

${\text{Pr}(X\geq\epsilon) \iff}$''${\mu(\{u\in\mathcal{A}:X(u)\in\mathcal{B}\})}$ for ${\mathcal{B}=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}:\alpha\geq\epsilon\}}$'' where $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, ${\mathcal{A}}$ is a subset of some  real or complex vector space ${\mathcal{V}}$, ${\text{Borel}(\mathcal{A})}$ is the collection of Borel subsets of ${\mathcal{A}}$, and ${\mu: Borel(\mathcal{A}) \to [0, 1]}$ is a Borel probability measure.

I do not understand what "sometimes coarse" refers to in this context.

Comment: Coarse means not tight

Comment: A coarse inequality is an inequality which requires little effort to show. For example $$\sin x \le 1$$ is coarse, while $$\sin x \le x - \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{5}x^5$$ is a tight inequality. Harder to prove, but also much more useful than the first one.

Comment: @Crostul your second inequality doesn't seem to hold